# What does deconstructible do in Python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

What does `deconstructible` decorator in Python do? I encountered this decorator looking at someone else code, but I have searched the Python docs and cannot find what this decorator actually does?

```
@deconstructible
class UserValidator(object):
    def __call__(self, value):
        if value:
           etc
```

Given the code above, what does adding 'deconstructible' do to this class?

Comment: this might be a self-created decorater. If that's the case noone can tell

Comment: Is django used? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/

Comment: [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By using Google I managed to find that it is part of Django:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method

> As long as all of the arguments to your class’ constructor are themselves serializable, you can use the @deconstructible class decorator from django.utils.deconstruct to add the deconstruct() method

Answer (score 6):

```
def deconstructible(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Class decorator that allow the decorated class to be serialized
    by the migrations subsystem.

    Accepts an optional kwarg `path` to specify the import path.
    """
```